# Why interrupt key ctl+c is active during OS boot up on ubuntu 22.04 any reason for not disabling during OS boot up process?

Tags: grub2, bootloader, init.d

When OS boots up on ubuntu 22.04 LTS, when ctl+c is pressed it halts or re-runs the installation. Any reason why ctl+c is not disabled? Can cons of considering enabling it?

When the user presses by mistake ctl+c it would rather halt the installation or re-run the installation during this phase.

Comment: Control-c can be used to skip the filesystem check during boot. In the old days it could be used to skip elements during boot but that was early kernel 4. I would consider what you have there is a bug and should be reported against the current kernel. I am on the border of calling this off topic (as it is probably generic and kernel related) ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind, is it good to disable ctrl+c key during OS booting?